ftp nlst command runs in Python, but not in Windows Command Line
I have exposed an API via python that connects to my ftp server via ftplib:
from ftplib import FTP    

@app.route('/api/ftp/list', methods=['GET'])
def ftp_list():
    remote_dir = request.args.get('remote_dir', '/')

    try:
        ftp = ftp_connect()
        #ftp.cwd(remote_dir)
        files = ftp.nlst()
        ftp.quit()
        return jsonify({'files': files}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

It retrieves the list of files via the NLST method successfully.
When I connect to my ftp server via Windows Command Line, I can't run the NLST method:
ftp> dir
200 'PORT' OK.
125 Data connection already open; starting 'BINARY' transfer.
-rw------- 1 tester users         95 Sep 19 20:34 testfile.txt
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 67 bytes received in 0.00Seconds 67000.00Kbytes/sec.
ftp> nlst
Invalid command.
ftp>


Is it becuase ftplib and Windows Command Line are basically two different ftp clients that have different methods implemented?
If the above is true, what would be the equivalent of nlst in Windows Command Line?


The interactive commands in the ftp command-line tool aren't the same as the commands in the FTP protocol.

Type help or ? to see the commands you can use in the ftp CLI.

Since your problem is with an interactive program, not with programming, this is off-topic for SO. [su] is the place to ask questions about using interactive Windows applications.

@Barmar I see. Thanks for the explanation

You're right, they are different clients that don't support all the same methods, even if the server does implement them. However, if you use something like WinSCP, you can send raw commands with call (including nlst), and the ftp client on Linux has nlist that essentially runs nlst. On Windows, you can use the ls command although the output is not identical.

NLST is FTP protocol command.
As with any other implementation of any other protocol (or whatever), different (FTP) client/libraries will have different API for accessing the functionality:

ftplib has FTP.nlst() method
Windows ftp client has ls command

Note that neither is simply mapped to NLST FTP command, as all file transfers and listings in FTP protocol are complex operations. They involve multiple commands and opening separate transfer connection. The NLST is just one (and the most significant) part of the whole operation.
